# Is there any way to send smses from EXPO without oppening the sms app?

Tags: android, react-native, sms, expo

I have tried to send smses from expo but it always opens the default sms app of my device. Is there any way to send an sms in the background? I would like to automate this process!

```js
  onPress = async () => {
    const status = await SMS.sendSMSAsync(
      'some_number',
      'message',
    )
    console.log('pressed');
  };
```

I would like to automate the sms sending process...

Comment: No way, opens the default UI/app for sending SMS messages with prefilled addresses and message.

Comment: And is there any way to automate the process of sending smses? Maybe not expo something else